# App Crashes aftter adding Admob Mediation Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

I integrated Google AdMob into our app. Everything worked perfectly when I added just Admob. But then we started implementing AdMob mediation. After we added the GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook pod app started crashing with the following exception

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[GADRequest sdkVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10334f240'
```

This is what we changed while implementing the mediation
In Podfile added the following,

```
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
```

When registering the admob,

```
func register() {
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        let ads = GADMobileAds.sharedInstance()
        ads.start { status in
            // Optional: Log each adapter's initialization latency.
            let adapterStatuses = status.adapterStatusesByClassName
            for adapter in adapterStatuses {
                let adapterStatus = adapter.value
                NSLog("Adapter Name: %@, Description: %@, Latency: %f", adapter.key,
                      adapterStatus.description, adapterStatus.latency)
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code logs the following,

```
2021-04-08 12:55:03.428056+0600 Quran Touch[542:38566] Adapter Name: GADMediationAdapterFacebook, Description: <GADAdapterStatus: 0x28158aa60; state = Not Ready;Adapter failed to initialize. Adapter raised an exception during setup. Adapter: GADMediationAdapterFacebook, Exception: +[GADRequest sdkVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10334f240>, Latency: 0.184458
2021-04-08 12:55:03.428157+0600 Quran Touch[542:38566] Adapter Name: GADMobileAds, Description: <GADAdapterStatus: 0x2815f01e0; state = Ready>, Latency: 0.022223
```

These are the only changes that we made to integrate mediation. When loading the banner or any other ad in the view, App Crashes

Comment: Have you fixed the problem above? I have the same problem. I've created ticket for that: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-mediation/issues/312

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by setting the exact version for Facebook Adapter in CocoaPods:

> pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook', '~> 6.3'

The exception happens since CocoaPods get older version of GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook on "pod update".